# Как сделать галлерею как на Яндекс.Картинках?

Tags: javascript

Т.е. как тут, с масштабированием изображений разного размера

https://yandex.ua/images/search?text=flower

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простейшее решение - использовать jQuery плагин Masonry или Isotope.

http://masonry.desandro.com/

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [Masonry.](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

И в блок засуньте картинку.

```
css:
img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы про масштабирование, то можно и с помощью css:

```css
.gallery-row{
  height:100px;
  margin-top:10px;
}

.gallery-img{
 display:inline-block;
 height:100px;
 border:1px solid grey;
 margin:0 5px;
}

.gallery-img img{
 height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-row">
  <div class="gallery-img">
     <img src = "http://dingo.com.ua/source/flowers/323.jpg"/>
  </div>
    <div class="gallery-img">
     <img src = "http://foneyes.ru/img/picture/Jun/09/31a890e8d9439ea09df6d4a0af2589a6/7.jpg"/>
  </div>
    <div class="gallery-img">
     <img src = "http://takefon.com/_ld/66/60326919.jpg"/>
  </div>
 </div>
<div class="gallery-row">
    <div class="gallery-img">
     <img src = "http://takefon.com/_ld/66/60326919.jpg"/>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-img">
     <img src = "http://dingo.com.ua/source/flowers/323.jpg"/>
  </div>
        <div class="gallery-img">
     <img src = "http://foneyes.ru/img/picture/Jun/09/31a890e8d9439ea09df6d4a0af2589a6/7.jpg"/>
  </div>
 </div>
```